# How can I change the class of a form button whenever I click, mouseoout or tab out of a field?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form, it has a button and a single form field.

This field accepts a MAC address and formats the MAC address when you tab out, or click on the VERIFY button to check if the MAC address is valid.

This is working fine.  What I've done, is firstly, disable the ANGULAR button so I don't have the user click on it UNTIL they've entered the MAC address, properly formatted or not.

Example: 5B53C6900000 is entered and when all is said and done, the act of moving OUT of the field or clicking on the VERIFY button, which becomes active when there's something in the fields, formats the address to this: 5B-53-C6-90-00-00.

That's all well and good, but I need to use ng-mouse-leave="" to change the CLASS of the button when the mouse leaves the focus area of the field.  The MAC address DOES NOT have to be properly formatted for this to occur.

Here are the parameters:

**form name:** formWizard
**field name:** newSystem.macAddress
**button name:** btnVerify
**disabled class:** btn-dead
**active class:** btn-standard

Here's the button and field code:

```
       <div class="wizard-step mac-address" data-ng-class="{ 'previous': step > 0, 'current': step == 0, 'next': step < 0, 'submitted': wizardForm.stepZeroSubmitted}">
            <section>
                <h2>MAC address</h2>
                <div class="grouping">
                    <div>
                        <div class="field-error" data-ng-show="(wizardForm.stepZeroSubmitted || wizardForm.macAddress.$dirty) && wizardForm.macAddress.$invalid">You must provide a valid MAC address to proceed.</div>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="00-11-AA-B0-22-CC" data-ng-model="newSystem.macAddress" name="macAddress" ng-maxlength="17" required ***ng-mouseleave="!wizardForm.macAddress.$invalid ? $scope.formWizard.btnVerify.btnStandard"*** />
                        <p class="small"><b>Total Device 3:</b> While on the main screen of the TTLDEVICE3, press the port key on the bottom right hand side. The MAC address will appear on the bottom of the screen.</p>
                        <p class="small"><b>Master Port:</b> The MAC address can be found on the label of the box and / or on the physical device.</p>
                    </div>
                    <button name="btnVerify" type="button" class="(newSystem.stepZeroSubmitted || newSystem.macAddress.$dirty) && newSystem.macAddress.$invalid ? btn-dead : btn-standard" data-ng-disabled="!newSystem.macAddress" data-ng-enabled="newSystem.macAddress" data-ng-click="verifyMacAddress()">Verify</button>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
```

The *** *** encapsulate my try...

Here's the error I get:

Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'undefined' expected : at column null of the expression [!wizardForm.macAddress.$invalid ? $scope.formWizard.btnVerify.btnStandard] starting at [!wizardForm.macAddress.$invalid ? $scope.formWizard.btnVerify.btnStandard].

```
at https://127.0.0.001/scripts/angular.js:78:12
at Parser.throwError (https://127.0.0.1/scripts/angular.js:9886:11)
at Parser.ternary (https://127.0.0.001/scripts/angular.js:10039:14)
at Parser.assignment (https://127.0.0.001/scripts/angular.js:10014:21)
at Parser.expression (https://127.0.0.001/scripts/angular.js:10010:17)
at Parser.filterChain (https://127.0.0.001/scripts/angular.js:9978:5)
at Parser.statements (https://127.0.0.001/scripts/angular.js:9955:30)
at Parser.parse (https://127.0.0.001/scripts/angular.js:9834:46)
at https://127.0.0.001/scripts/angular.js:10654:37
at Object.compile (https://127.0.0.001/scripts/angular.js:17868:20) angular.js:9402(anonymous function)
```

IGNORE the 127.0.0.001 it's BOGUS...

Comment: I may be missing the point of the question, but can't you just use ng-class on the button and check the conditions there?

Comment: Ah, yeah... D'oh... let me check in plunker... standby

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the rest of the ternary statement [condition] ? [if true] : [if false]

Comment: Better:  <input type="text" placeholder="00-11-AA-B0-22-CC" data-ng-model="newSystem.macAddress" name="macAddress" ng-maxlength="17" required ng-mouseleave="!wizardForm.macAddress.$invalid ? $scope.formWizard.btnVerify.btn-standard : $scope.formWizard.btnVerify.btn-dead" />

Comment: OK, that got rid of the error completely: YAY! But the button class doesn't change when I move the mouse out of range of the field.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's what I found:

By taking the suggestion of Matt Burrow, which I tried, it did work, partially, but still did not solve the problem of having the class of the button change when I moved the mouse OUT of focus of the boundary of the text field.

So here's what I did. I took Matty M's suggestion and researched ngClass and this is WHAT works... Thanks both Matt's for helping.

```
        <div class="wizard-step mac-address" data-ng-class="{ 'previous': step > 0, 'current': step == 0, 'next': step < 0, 'submitted': wizardForm.stepZeroSubmitted}">
            <section>
                <h2>MAC address</h2>
                <div class="grouping">
                    <div>
                        <div class="field-error" data-ng-show="(wizardForm.stepZeroSubmitted || wizardForm.macAddress.$dirty) && wizardForm.macAddress.$invalid">You must provide a valid MAC address to proceed.</div>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="00-11-AA-B0-22-CC" data-ng-model="newSystem.macAddress" ng-mouseleave="btnChng='btn-standard'" name="macAddress" ng-maxlength="17" required  />
                        <p class="small"><b>INVERTER 3:</b> While on the main screen of the INVERTER 3, press the port key on the bottom right hand side. The MAC address will appear on the bottom of the screen.</p>
                        <p class="small"><b>Main Port:</b> The MAC address can be found on the label of the box and / or on the physical device.</p>
                    </div>
                    <button name="btnVerify" class="btn-dead" ng-class="btnChng" type="button" data-ng-click="verifyMacAddress()">Verify</button>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
```

So that's what works... thanks guys. If you want to make additional comments, please do.